# Foreach skip option value

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to figure out how to remove language id 10 from the loop.

```
 <? foreach ($languages as $langId => $langDetails): ?>
            <option value="<?=$langId?>" <?=($langId == zbanRegistry::getInstance()->lang) ? 'selected="selected"' : NULL;?>><?=$langDetails['LABEL']?></option>            
            <? endforeach; ?>
```

and the result is:

```
<select name="lang" id="lang" >
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Language 1</option>           
    <option value="2" >Language 2</option>          
    <option value="3" >Language 3</option>          
    <option value="4" >Language 4</option>          
    <option value="5" >Language 5</option>          
    <option value="6" >Language 6</option>          
    <option value="7" >Language 7</option>          
    <option value="8" >Language 8</option>          
    <option value="9" >Language 9</option>          
    <option value="10" >Language 10</option>                    
</select>
```

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: add an if test if $langId != 10 around echoing out your option values

Comment: use unset function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: You can skip an iteration with `if($langId == 10){ continue; }` at the beginning of your for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of langId. Maybe something like that?

```
<? foreach ($languages as $langId => $langDetails): ?>
    <? if ($langId != 10): ?>
        <option value="<?=$langId?>" <?=($langId == zbanRegistry::getInstance()->lang) ? 'selected="selected"' : NULL;?>><?=$langDetails['LABEL']?></option>            
    <? endif; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please note that `<?` tag is a *shorttag*, this has to be enabled, otherwise you will get an error. In the question this was used, therefor is it answered with them aswell.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. Simplicity at it best :)